# br_netfilter missing in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, docker, modprobe

I have the following problem when running docker.io:

> Running modprobe bridge nf_nat br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found.

I tried running `modprobe br_netfilter` which results in:

```
modprobe br_netfilter
modprobe: FATAL: Module br_netfilter not found.
```

What can I do to install br_netfilter on my system?

Thanks!

From the comments:

```
uname -r
3.16.0-49-generic
```

.

```
apt-cache policy linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic
linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic:
  Installed: 3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1
  Candidate: 3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

.

```
find /lib/modules/ -type f -name '*br_netfilter.ko'
```

Did not return anything. Maybe unrelated, but I have this directory: `/lib/modules/3.16.0-49-generic/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter` and it contains several .ko files, but not br_netfilter.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -r`

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache-policy linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic`

Comment: And the output of `find /lib/modules/ -type f -name '*br_netfilter.ko' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need at least Kernel version `3.19.0-15` and therefore Vivid. Check this URLs for [Vivid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=br_netfilter.ko&mode=exactfilename&suite=vivid&arch=any) and [Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=br_netfilter.ko).

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors, the reason why `br_netfilter` fails to load is because it has been a built-in module. Only since kernel version 3.18, `br_netfilter` has become a separate module.

See also:

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13969
- http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ebtables
```